# I want to show names of models that start with a letter y rather than a viewer?

Tags: c#

problem

```
 public static void Carbycountry()
    {

        SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection("server=LAPTOP-G0RLHB36\\SQLEXPRESS01;database=singog;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        SqlCommand mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand();
        mySqlCommand.CommandText = "select * from cars where  model like  'y% ' ;";
        mySqlConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader mySqlDataReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();


        Console.WriteLine("{0,10} {1,10} {2,10} {3,10} {4,10} ", "ID CARS", "MODELS", "WeightS", "COYNTRYS", "PRICES");
        Console.WriteLine();
        while (mySqlDataReader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,10} 1,10} {2,10} {3,10 } {4,10}", mySqlDataReader["idcar"], mySqlDataReader["model"], mySqlDataReader["weight"], mySqlDataReader["country"], mySqlDataReader["price"]);
        }

        mySqlDataReader.Close();
        mySqlConnection.Close();
    }
```

I want to show names of models that start with a letter y rather than a viewer??

Comment: "Rather than a viewer"? What's wrong with your code? What's the output you get, what's the expected output?

Comment: Not clear what are you asking, but that space in _'y% '_ is really wrong.

Comment: What I want the user to click on the number seven is to have all the models starting with the letter y

Comment: I sent all the code down